# How to throw exception when i have open two or three windows

Tags: java, selenium

I have two or three open (in different cases) windows and trying to throw Exception to start the next test.
When I write:

```
throw new RuntimeException("anything");
```

the new popup window show with text: "The webpage you are viewing is trying to close the window. Do you want to close this window" and script stop.

Browser: Internet Explorer 8
I know, that this window shows when I try close window.

Comment: Show your current code and how you attempted to implement it. You gotta show some effort. Also, we can't help if we don't know when new windows are being created

Comment: I am not able to understand this question. Are you trying to handle the popup window?

Comment: Do you mean window or tabs ?

Comment: @LittlePanda no, When new window show I'm trying throw Exception.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I add my code:

```
   //my methods
public static boolean switchToWindowAboutTitle(WebDriver driver, String title){
        String currentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
        Set<String> availableWindows = driver.getWindowHandles();
        try{
        if(!availableWindows.isEmpty()){
            for(String windowId : availableWindows){
                String switchedTitle = driver.switchTo().window(windowId).getTitle();
                if(switchedTitle.equals(title) || switchedTitle.contains(title))
                    return true;
                else{
                    driver.switchTo().window(currentWindow);
                }
            }
        }
        }catch(NoSuchWindowException ignore){
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }

//my code:  

//my main window -- window title: "Main"
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
driver.switchTo().frame("Main");

//click on button which open new window
driver.findElement(byDetermineButton).click();

//window title: "Authorize"
switchToWindowAboutTitle(driver, "Authorize");

new WebDriverWait(driver, 180).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(byProduct));
driver.findElement(byProduct).click();

try {
                                Thread.sleep(10000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
System.out.println(driver.getWindwHandles().size());     //show 3
//after click when window size == 3 I'd like throw exception because this means that my product isn't available --> this third window show information about it.
if(driver.getWindowHandles().size() == 3){
    throw new RuntimeException("test");
}
```

When I execute code: throw new RuntimeException("test"); Internet Explorer show alert:
"The webpage you are viewing is trying to close the window.
Do you want to close this window?" And I have two options: Yes or No.

Why I can't throw Exception :(